# Managing Outlook meeting requests programmatically (incl. attendees) with ical

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I have a system (written in PHP) where users can book meeting rooms. The system should send meeting requests to the users and they should be able to add other attendees to this meeting.

Currently, I partly solved this by creating iCalendar events that are sent to the users by email. The problem is that Outlook (used by **all** the users) does not offer the possibility to add any attendees to the event (I guess that's because it's a meeting request created by an external program?).
The only option they have is to forward the request. But this has several downsides, e.g. no connection to the booking system anymore.

QUESTION: Is there a way to manage the meeting requests **including** managing attendees programmatically in PHP?

The main problem seems to be adding attendees.
I tried to have something like the following ics file but attendees are just ignored.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="First LASTNAME";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:First.LASTNAME@domain.tld
ATTENDEE;CN="First LASTNAME2";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:First.LASTNAME2@domain.tld
CLASS:PUBLIC
UID:' . $booking->id . '
SEQUENCE:' . $booking->sequence_id . '
DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd\THis', $booking->created).'
DTSTART:' . $booking->start . '
DTEND:' . $booking->end . '
SUMMARY:' . $booking->subject. '
LOCATION:' . $booking->location . '
CREATED:'.date('Ymd\THis', $booking->changed).'
DESCRIPTION:' . $booking->description . '
X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple attendees can be specified by including multiple "ATTENDEE"
properties within the calendar component.

http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/attendee.html

You're almost there you just have to add in your list of attendee's (you're only adding the primary at the moment)
as long as you add them in with the exchange email address it'll automatically add them into outlook and populate everyones calendar.  If you don't use exchange you'll need to send the ical out to all attendee's too

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You mean adding another line like ATTENDEE;CN="First LASTNAME2";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:First.LASTNAME2@domain.tld etc? I tried that (sorry not shown in the example) but it did not add the new attendee in Outlook :(

Comment: If you get it right it does (I use exactly the same solution in my platform) now outlook is fickle you may have to specify ldap destinations for the users if you're running an exchange server,  Read the specs linked they give examples of multiple attendee's with organiser + 2+ attendees

Comment: I don't seem to get it to work :( So you managed to send a ics file as an email to several users where they were set as attendees? And the users were able to see the other attendees? I even saved a meeting (that was created in Outlook) with attendees from Outlook as  an ics file and opened the file. No attendees!  Could this be a problem with Outlook 2003?

Comment: Could be I had no problems it only populated full data for people within the same active directory as the others in the attendees but those outside were just listed as "outside organisation attendees" I did it in both vcal and ical formats.

Comment: I encounter the same problem under Outlook 2010. I explicit set ATTENDEE number >= 2 but when i send the email only one ATTENDEE is showed. Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @saveandload.com did you guys ever figure out a solution to this problem? ran into this today.

Comment: Try: ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="your_name":mailto:your_email